# NAudio Only picking up Microphone input sound when another app is using the same microphone

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, microphone, noise

I am trying to create an application that records the mic input and puts its volume in a progress bar as a sort of noise-o-meter. I have the audio input devices set and all working but the mic is only receiving microphone input noise when another application is using the same microphone device. When I close the said application, it doesn't read the microphone sound again.

This is my code:

```cs
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeAudioDevices();
  timer1.Start();
}

// to initialize audio devices in the computer
private void InitializeAudioDevices() {
  var waveIn = new WaveIn();
  waveIn.StartRecording();

  MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
  // Initialize MMDeviceEnumerator
  // Get the collection of audio capture devices (input devices)
  var captureDevices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);
  Input.Items.AddRange(captureDevices.ToArray());
  var defaultInput = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Console);

  // Loop through devices to select default Input device
  for (int i = 0; i < Input.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (Input.Items[i].ToString() == defaultInput.ToString()) {
      Input.SelectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Get the collection of audio render devices (output devices)
  var renderDevices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);
  Output.Items.AddRange(renderDevices.ToArray());
  var defaultOutput = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);

  // Loop through devices to select default Output device
  for (int i = 0; i < Output.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (Output.Items[i].ToString() == defaultOutput.ToString()) {
      Output.SelectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}

public static MMDevice singleDevice;

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  if (Input.SelectedItem != null) {
    var singleDevice = (MMDevice) Input.SelectedItem;
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(singleDevice.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100);
    label3.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
    var waveIn = new WaveIn();
    waveIn.DeviceNumber = Input.SelectedIndex;
  }
}
```

I tried many ways like trying to use the

```
var waveIn = new WaveIn(); 
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick or I may be using it wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using WasapiCapture instead of WaveIn? You are mixing two completely different Windows Audio APIs and you will probably have most success if you stick to WASAPI.